# Magento: Minimal quantity different sizes

Tags: magento

I'm making a shop with clothing. But there is a minimal order amount per order. Now i want to have a choice that the customer can make with different sizes.

So the minimal count is 10 pieces, and if a customer wants 4 size M, 5 size L and 1 size XL. what is the easiest way in code that i can accomplish this?

I'm using simple products associated with configurable products.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help :)

[How to get the Total Quantity Of All the Items In your Shopping Cart](http://wabism.com/magento-shopping-cart-total-quantity-vs-total-items/)